# Seasoned Advice swag for top users

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 950 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Seasoned Advice t-shirt in your size
- Seasoned Advice die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: cooking.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: cooking.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Very nice, thanks (again). I've only just changed my e-mail profile e-mail address to a valid one, have the e-mails been sent yet?

Comment: Yes, I got one.

Comment: @Ray what time did you get yours?

Comment: Here's a T-shirt size conversion chart, for people outside of the U.S. http://www.meixsell.com/EbayInfo/WWconversion.html

Comment: At 3:57 AM EDT.

Comment: I'd rather have the [cards](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/seasoned-advice-moderator-cards) ... there's no way I'd ever wear the shirt ... of course, to get either, I'd have to tell you my address, which I'm not willing to do.

Comment: There's also a surprise, cooking-themed item that will be coming with your packages that I am super excited about getting out to you all. It's a semi-secret though, so I will just add a picture once they come in.

Comment: @KateyΨ: Surprise item? Did Joel manage to pick up his cookbooks from eBay?

Comment: It's literally Jeff Atwood jumping out of your pantry at you. Serious surprise.

Comment: I didn't get my package yet and I filled in my information the day after we were able to. Did anyone else get their package yet? I'm in Canada.

Comment: @Kyra: Haven't received mine yet, either, and I'm in the US. I suspect the problem is Jeff has been eating all the goodies out of everyone's pantries, and due to the resulting weight gain is now too expensive to FedEx.

Comment: @derobert lol I'm glad that I'm not the only one. :)

Comment: @Kyra: According to [the comments on this answer](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/a/1251/160), they're being mailed this week.

Comment: @derobert Thank you for letting me know :)

Answer (score 5):

The swag has arrived! And it includes an apron in addition to the t-shirt and pens and stuff. Very nice!

<sub>(Now I feel guilty for not participating here as much as some others.)</sub>

Comment: The apron is fantastic! I'm planning on changing my SE picture to include the apron.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the swag. The apron is awesome.

BUT, that did NOT need to require a signature. I had to go to the post office to pick up a t-shirt? They couldn't have left that on my door? Please don't send out future packages with signature required for delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the swag! I absolutely love the apron and I am already wearing the shirt. Thank you so much :D