# I didn't get any email about the swag

Tags: support, swag

In [Seasoned Advice swag for top users](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/seasoned-advice-swag-for-top-users) is reported that users in the first two pages in the all-the-time reputation list, with a reputation higher than 950, would soon receive an email from Stack Exchange.

I still have to receive such email. Is there anybody else who didn't eceive that email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We at Stack HQ will look into this to see if we missed you somehow, but in the meantime:

1. Is the email address you provided (when you registered for the site) a valid
   account?
2. Have you checked your spam filter to see if it got marked
   as junk?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't reply before, but I didn't get any notification about this answer. Yes, my email is still valid, and there isn't any message sent from Stack Exchange that is marked as spam.

Comment: I didn't get any email, though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno If you send me your mailing address (email: laura [at] stackexchange.com ), I'll add you to the list. The packages are actually just being put together now; they'll be mailed out in the next week. I'll confirm with you when I receive your email/shipping info.

Comment: Just to let you know, Laura, that my swag pack arrived this week. Thanks for your time.